# Angular app/widget on multiple web pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, web

I am building a chat application similar to google hangouts. I have managed to get it right so far. The only problem i am experiencing now is having the angular app/widget run on other pages when i change url's and the app remaining fixed or being restarted on the other web page. how would i have to structure or place the app onto a site.

The app looks like this on my index.html in the angular app.

here is an image: http://s12.postimg.org/jkgraguod/live_review_one.png

I would now like to have the same app/widget run on another pages after it loads e.g reviews.html

I am using laravel (webservice) for posts and gets. the app is in angular, standalone thus far and i would like to keep it that way.

If you would like me to be more clear please feel free to ask :)

All Files Added to plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/yDoUfw?p=info

code in app.js (routes)

app.config(function($routeProvider) {

```
    $routeProvider

    .when('/chat-rooms', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/chat-rooms.html',
        controller: 'ChatRoomsCtrl'
    })

    .when('/chat-room/:chatRoom', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/chat-room.html',
        controller: 'ChatRoomCtrl'
    })

    .when('/chat-room-pop/:chatRoom', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/chat-room-pop.html',
        controller: 'ChatRoomCtrl'
    });

});
```

My index.html page.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="css/hanger.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body ng-app="chatApp">

    <div class="page-header">
        <h2>live review single page</h2>
    </div>

    <div ng-view class="container"></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-scroll-glue/src/scrollglue.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-clear/angular.dcb-clear-input.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/hanger/hanger.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/chat-rooms.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/chat-room.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/services/message.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services/chat-room.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services/webservice.js"></script>
</body>
```

All Files Added to plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/yDoUfw?p=info

Comment: So this chat actually look like a widget right ? If you have a controller and a template dedicated to this part you could add it simply using ng-include and ng-controller where you want it to be.

Comment: Could you provide some clue about how you implemented this chat ?

Comment: We seem to be on the same page :)  let me give it a try, if i fail i will post up some code. Thank you thus far

Comment: Tell me if it was ok for you so i can post this advice as an answer.

Comment: Sure thing! will do. I should have response in the next 30mins

Comment: Alright, Okazari, i am think i am starting to understand my problem a little more now. I used ng-include and directed that to my index.html 

It was able to include but on the page load it did not show the app. I think this is because i am not pointing to my route which initiates the view or template. I am updating my post with the routes in app.js to give a better idea of how it is working. also note when i visit the url in the route thats when the app works

Comment: using the same template and the same controller for differents view isn't a really good practice. Anyway, i guess you need this ":chatRoom" value to be able to init the widget. I think you will need to build a directive that include the chat and take a var which will contain the room id.

Comment: If you can provide a plunker that reproduce (or simulate) your works, it would be a great tool to provide you a clean solution. (after lunch)

Comment: I have "created" the project on plunk. I was not able to make file structures (i dont think they allow that?) So i renamed file names to make sense like chat-room-service.js etc i didn't add in the libraries like bootstrap etc. please have a look at the plunk creation here: http://plnkr.co/edit/yDoUfw?p=info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand your desire, you want to run some pieces of html in any place. 
I'd create a directive chat-app and a controller sets some cfg for it. So you would have it multiple times in one page(if each chat talks to the same api interface, each will display the same content) or multiple pages.

after that a chat-page would look like

```
<div class="chatpage">
 <my-chat-directive api="{{chat.apiPoint}}" ng-repeat="chat in chats" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, i will look into this and return with feedback

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered looking at ui-router for your client-side routing?  It supports multiple named views, which means that your 'top-level' page template can include a ui-view for your chat widget and a ui-view for your dynamic page content, e.g. reviews, etc.

There's an example (and links to the ui-router docs) here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views.

I can highly recommend it as a replacement for the out-of-the-box AngularJS routing - it's so configurable and supports really nice hierarchies.

Comment: @Scripta55 I definitly think this is a good way to handle the problem. You could have a global template with the permanent chat. Inside this you will have the changing content. You could add a service to manage the visibility of the chat. That's a good way to go.

Comment: thanks, i will look into this and return with feedback